# How to display XXX|XXX for every number in an index of an array? - Java

Tags: java

So I have the NIM Game Program. Basically, there are four piles and the two players have to keep taking stones from the piles until one of them lose. Right now my piles look like this in the output.

Board: [1, 2, 3, 4]

but I need to modify it so it will look like this

```
                        XXX|XXX
                XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
        XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
```

This is my code

```
System.out.print("");
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i];j++)
        {
            //System.out.println(j);
            
            System.out.print(" XXX|XXX ");
            
            
            
        }
        
        System.out.println(" ");
        
    }
```

it prints this

XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX

suggestons?

Comment: Please share the full code which isn't working with the error.

Answer (score 1):

By making use of an `array` and the `String.join()` method, you can create an array that has a length of the last number in the board array. This ensures that all of the strings included in the output will be of the same length - no ugly, accidental single-character offsets. Then, you can loop through the numbers that are less than the length of the pile array and check to see if that position should be blank spaces or filled with "XXX|XXX"

Afterwards, you would have arrays that look like this:

```
{"       ","       ","       ","XXX|XXX"}
{"       ","       ","XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX"}
{"       ","XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX"}
{"XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX","XXX|XXX"}
```

```java
int [] board = {1,2,3,4};

for (int i : board) {
    String[] pile = new String[board[board.length-1]];
    for (int x = 0; x < pile.length; x++) {
        if (x < pile.length-i) {
            pile[x] = "       ";
        } else {
            pile[x] = "XXX|XXX";
        }
    }
    String s = String.join(" ", pile);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
                        XXX|XXX
                XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
        XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
```

This loop is also capable of supporting a board of any length, so long as each item in the board increases by 1.

Comment: when i do that, it doesn't print out. This is the code I am using which has the errors. I have updated the code.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code in my answer into your `main()` method? What do you mean when you say, "It doesn't print out?"

Answer (score 0):

something like this can help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [] board={1,2,3,4};
       
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i]; j++) {
                System.out.print("XXX|XXX ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
            
        }
    }
```