# How to invert the output in Nim Game?

Tags: java

So I have the NIM Game Program. Basically, there are four piles and the two players have to keep taking stones from the piles until one of them lose. Right now my piles look like this in the output.

Board: [1, 2, 3, 4]

XXX|XXX represents one stone and one column of them represent a pile
but I need to modify it so it will look like this

```
                        XXX|XXX
                XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
        XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
```

This is my code

```
System.out.print("");
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    //System.out.println(i);
    for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i];j++) {
        //System.out.println(j);
        System.out.print(" XXX|XXX ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

it prints this

```
XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX

XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX XXX|XXX
```

suggestons?

Comment: Perhaps you could delete your [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64362585/6367213) question, as it seems to be a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

First, imagine your output as a virtual 2D `String` array, as hinted by @gmdev in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64366905/6367213):

```
String[][] output = {
    {"       ", "       ", "       ", "XXX|XXX"},
    {"       ", "       ", "XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX"},
    {"       ", "XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX"},
    {"XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX", "XXX|XXX"}
};
```

Next, you need to somehow find out how tall your highest pile is. Here's one way to do so in Java 8 or later:

```
int tallestPileLevel = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
```

Then you render your virtual 2D array one line at a time.

The outer loop descends down your pile levels and the inner loop prints:

- air (`"       "`) --> if the `i`-th pile doesn't reach the current `level`
- stone (`"XXX|XXX"`) --> otherwise

Here's a working example:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PrintNim {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int tallestPileLevel = Arrays.stream(numbers).max().getAsInt();
        
        String stone = " XXX|XXX ";
        String air   = "         ";
        
        for (int level = tallestPileLevel; level > 0; level--) {
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] < level) {
                    System.out.print(air);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(stone);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use another `for` loop to set however many spaces you need to stack the stones. I made a string that is the same length as 1 stone. The for loop repeats this string 3 times, then twice, etc.

I added code comments to try to help with the explanation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("");
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int[] spaceNum = {3, 2, 1, 0}; //to stack the x's you need 3 spaces, then 2, etc.
    String spaces = "         "; //length of 1 stone, i.e " XXX|XXX "
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        //this loop uses sapceNum to decide how far to indent before the next loop writes the stones
        for(int k = spaceNum[i]; k > 0; k--) {
            System.out.print(spaces);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < numbers[i]; j++) {
            System.out.print(" XXX|XXX ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
    }
}
```

output:

```
                            XXX|XXX  
                   XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX  
          XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX  
 XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX  XXX|XXX
```

Comment: You've presupposed that the height of the tallest pile will always be 4.

Comment: What if pile heights aren't ordered? How would you print the following pile array using your logic: `[1, 4, 3, 2]`?

Comment: @JanezKuhar I just saw this comment now, sorry for delayed reply. I could easily make a function to reverse the `numbers` array and write it to `spaceNum` using a for loop,  but since it is just setting up a board for a game I figured the number was fixed. I didn't want to confuse the OP with more code than was necessary.